# jsf dynamic tag from string

Tags: jsf, dynamic, tags

i want to show some data to the user

the data maybe represented to user by different JSF tags based on a configuration

for example some times it may represented by text

and sometimes it may represented by graphical symbol or even chart

also i want that this representation be customizable.

how could i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the `rendered` attribute.

```
<h:outputText value="#{bean.value}" rendered="#{bean.datatype == 'text'}" />
<h:graphicImage value="#{bean.value}" rendered="#{bean.datatype == 'image'}" />
<x:someChart value="#{bean.value}" rendered="#{bean.datatype == 'chart'}" />
```

Whenever the boolean expression in the `rendered` attribute evaluates to `true`, the component will be rendered (displayed), otherwise not (hidden). In the above example the `Bean#getDataType()` should return a `String` or an `Enum`.

Here are another examples of how to use boolean expressions in EL:

```
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.booleanValue}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.intValue > 10}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.objectValue == null}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.stringValue != 'someValue'}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{!empty bean.collectionValue}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{!bean.booleanValue && bean.intValue != 0}" />
<h:someComponent rendered="#{bean.enumValue == 'FOO' || bean.enumValue == 'BAR'}" />
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. it seems that it will be work. but how could i make it customizable? i mean that read tag name and their setting from some configuration at runtime?